# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined

Tags: javascript, command, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, I learned mostly v11 of discord.js, When  I was creating a unban command in discord, and then when i was finished, I ran the command and it gave the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined" and here is my code. **its a command handler by the way**

```
module.exports = {
    name : 'unban',
    execute(client, message, args){
       if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("You dont have permission to perform this command!")
    if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("You need to provide an ID.")
    let bannedMember =  client.users.fetch(args[0])
        if(!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("Please provide a user id to unban someone!")

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!reason) reason = "No reason given!"

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("I dont have permission to perform this command!")|
    message.delete()
    try {
        message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, reason)
        message.channel.send(`**${bannedMember.tag}** has been unbanned from the guild!`)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
}




No idea what the problem is.
```

Comment: log what `message.guild` is and add a code block showing the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `message.guild.me.hasPermission` and `message.member.hasPermission` are all valid methods. Are you sure that the `message` variable is defined? Check your command handler.

Comment: It's defined, the issue is `.me` is not defined, while `message` and `message.guild` are defined

Comment: maybe you can try doing `var me = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);` and then replace `message.guild.me` with `me`